# Reflect.Value issues

Tags: go, reflect

In trying to test this business func:

```
//IsInSlice works like Array.prototype.find in JavaScript, except it
// returns -1 if `value` is not found. (Also, Array.prototype.find takes
// function, and IsInSlice takes `value` and `list`)
func IsInSlice(value interface{}, list interface{}) int {
    slice := reflect.ValueOf(list)

    for i := 0; i < slice.Len(); i++ {
        if slice.Index(i) == value {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

I find that it fails my sanity tests:

```
func TestIsInSlice(t *testing.T) {
    digits := []int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    slice := digits[3:8] // returns {3,4,5,6,7}

    type args struct {
        value interface{}
        list  interface{}
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want int
    }{
        {
            name: "SanityTest",
            args: args{value: 3,
                list: []int{3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            },
            want: 0,
        },
        {
            name: "ElementAtEnd",
            args: args{
                value: 5,
                list:  slice,
            },
            want: 3,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := IsInSlice(tt.args.value, tt.args.list); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("IsInSlice() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }

}
```

The person responsible for fixing these bugs has no idea what is causing the bug, let alone how to fix it, and neither do me or the senior dev. So, I attempted to [isolate the problem](https://play.golang.org/p/ukoe_bjhs6m) to try to identify it.

**What I thought it was**

When I logged the bugs, I thought they were because somehow, the `value` was being compared to the `reflect.Value` returned by `slice.Index(i)`. I tried

```
reflect.DeepEqual(slice.Index(i), value)
```

but that fails. The only way I could get passing test is to use `Int()` to extract the value and use

```
var i int64 = 3
```

instead of the literal `3`, which is flaky af.

**What is the issue and how do we fix it?**

Comment: The underlying problem is the attempt to write a generic function. You cannot do this. E.g. try to find a NaN in a slice of float64.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a valid question regarding a core golang package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Index() method](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Interface) returns a reflect.Value. 
Use that value's [Interface() method](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Interface) to get its underlying value and compare to that:

```
func IsInSlice(value interface{}, list interface{}) int {
    slice := reflect.ValueOf(list)
    for i := 0; i < slice.Len(); i++ {
        if slice.Index(i).Interface() == value {
            return i
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

Comment: How tf did I overlook this when studying [the API specifications](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)?!

Answer (score 1):

`Value.Index()` returns a `reflect.Value`. Comparing this to the `interface{}` you receive will *never* return true. You'd need to compare against the "real" value by using `slice.Index(i).Interface()`.

*However*, you're messing with black magic here. You're missing a lot of safety checks - what if `list` isn't actually a slice or array? What if `value` isn't of the same type as `list`'s elements? Take a look at the implementation of `DeepEqual` to see the kind of checks you might want to perform for a function like this: https://golang.org/src/reflect/deepequal.go